# geom_boxplot adjust the location of one box

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot using `geom_box`. My current code is:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Condition,y=pct,color = Condition), data=all_sub2_eyes)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=HA/FL),data=sub,color="green")+
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y="CoP/Foot Length",
       title="Average Normalized CoP Position")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=.5,size=8))
```

Now I get the graph:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjx7I.png)

My goal is to move the green box right below the pink and blue boxes and add a legend for it called "ankle position". Is there any method to achieve that?

The plot I need:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Do you want it below the other boxplots and on the same axis? Do you want it centered? Or, maybe you want a separate plot entirely? Please provide more detail regarding how you want the final product to look.

Comment: Yea I want the green box shift to the center of this graph. They are using the same axis.

Comment: Do you want a completely separate legend for the ‘Ankle Joint’ boxplot?

Comment: It would be better if the legend for Ankle Joint is with the other two conditions. Just like the plot above.

Comment: It is hard to reproduce something equivalent as your boxes come from two different data sources. Can you post a subset of your data so I can work with it?